# Проверка наличия изображения по ссылке

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Например, есть 2 ссылки:

```
https://new.vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png (ссылка на изображение)
https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png (битая ссылка, 404-ая страница)
```

В программе надо загрузить 30000 изображений, некоторые ссылки будут битыми. Как сделать проверку на наличие изображения по ссылке? Можно, конечно же, загрузить 1-ый раз как страницу и проверить на любой html тег (например, `<html>`), и если нет этого тега - загрузить 2-ой раз как изображение, но этот костыль не поможет при таких больших объёмах, ибо придётся дважды загружать одно и тоже, в большинстве случаев.

Comment: А что, HTTP-ответы проверить не судьба? Ну, там, поля `Status`, `Content-Type`... (кстати, что значит "загрузить как изображение"?)

Comment: `using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) { client.DownloadFile(*ссылка*, *путь*); }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, можно так:

```
static async Task<byte[]> GetContentOrNull(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // если вернулся плохой статус
            return null;                   // возвращаем null
        using (var content = response.Content) // иначе читаем контент
            return await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Вы можете проверить более точно код возврата `responce.HttpStatusCode`, если хотите.

Если нужно сохранить в файл, используйте `content.CopyToAsync` вместо `content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync`.

---

Для запроса лишь существования файла можно было бы использовать `HEAD` вместо `GET`:

```
static async Task<bool> CheckContent(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri)))
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

но для обеих ваших ссылок сервер возвращает `501 Not implemented`.

Comment: Можно попробовать запрашивать Range — с первого по второй байты. :)

Comment: Если не поддерживается HEAD, то наверняка и частичное скачивание тоже. Но да, стоило попробовать :)